# Attribute points in an array

Tags: python, arrays

The principle of the program is to get a final ranking according the performance of the  soccer player (the number of goals). Therefore I must to attribute points according the number of the goals.

There are 3 soccer players only and the ranking is from smallest to biggest according the number of goals. 
There are two rounds more a final ranking. I must to learn to manipulate arrays and functions (not use functions zip,  sorted, etc…)

Here are my arrays

name = ["Henry", "Owen", "Drogba"]  => the name of the soccer player

goal1 = [18, 12, 6] => it’s about of the number of goals during the first round for each player

goal2 = [6, 8, 5] => it’s about of the number of goals during the second round for each player

gain = [2,4,6] => score to attribute according the number of goal If you marked the most of goals you will have 6 points. So the maximum.

I don’t know if it’s clear ? Sorry for my English.

My problem, I have another array  point = [0,0,0] how I could get total points  in this array for the final ranking ? For each round I will wish to add up the new points with current points.

After I will wish to get a preview of the final ranking with a new function.
Thank you a lot.

```
def printOne(name, goal, title, current_pts):
    print("\t\t\t\t{}\n".format(title))
    for i in range(len(name)):
        print("\t\t\t\t {} \t {} points {} goals".format(name[i], gain[i] ,goal[i]))
    print("=======================================================")
    return current_pts

def sort(name, goal1, goal2, pts):
    swap = True
    while swap:
        swap = False
        for i in range(len(name) - 1):
            if goal1[i + 1] < goal1[i]:
                name[i], name[i + 1] = name[i + 1], name[i]
                goal1[i], goal1[i + 1] = goal1[i + 1], goal1[i]
                goal2[i], goal2[i + 1] = goal2[i + 1], goal2[i]
                pts[i], pts[i + 1] = pts[i + 1], pts[i]
                swap = True
    return name, goal1, goal2, pts

def test(name, goal, pts):
  for i in range(len(name)):
    goalTotal.append(goal1[i] + goal2[i])
    print(name[i] + " \t  ????  points \t   " + str(goalTotal[i]) + " goals : ")

  return name, goal, pts   


name = ["Henry", "Owen", "Drogba"]
point = [0,0,0]
goal1 = [18, 12, 6]
goal2 = [6, 8, 5]
gain = [2,4,6]
goalTotal = []


name, goal1, goal2, point = sort(name, goal1, goal2, point)
point = printOne(name, goal1, "First round", point)

name, goal2, goal1, point = sort(name, goal2, goal1, point)
point = printOne(name, goal2, "Second round", point)

test(name, goalTotal, "Ranking total ")
```

Here is the result

```
First round
Drogba    2 points 6 buts        
Owen      4 points 8 buts        
Henry     6 points 10 buts     
=======================================================
Second round

Henry     2 points 4 buts     
Drogba    4 points 5 buts     
Owen      6 points 6 buts     
=======================================================
Final Ranking
Drogba    6 points
Henry     8 points
Owen      10 points
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure if I understand correctly but do you mean something like this?

```
import numpy as np
def printOne(name,gain, goal, title, current_pts):
    print("\t\t\t\t{}\n".format(title))
    for i in range(len(name)):
        print("\t\t\t\t {} \t {} points {} buts \t {} total points".format(name[i], gain[i] ,goal[i],current_pts[i]))
    print("=======================================================")
    return current_pts

def trier( goal, pts, gain):
    minIndex = goal.index(min(goal))
    maxIndex = goal.index(max(goal))
    middleIndex = 0
    if minIndex + maxIndex == 2:
        middleIndex = 1
    elif minIndex + maxIndex == 1:
        middleIndex = 2
    gain_per_person = [0,0,0]

    gain_per_person[maxIndex] = gain[2]
    gain_per_person[middleIndex] = gain[1]
    gain_per_person[minIndex] = gain[0]
    pts = np.add(pts, gain_per_person)
    return gain_per_person, pts


name = ["Henry", "Owen", "Drogba"]
point = [0,0,0]
goal1 = [18, 12, 6]
goal2 = [6, 8, 5]
gain = [2,4,6]

gain1, point = trier(goal1, point, gain)
point = printOne(name, gain1, goal1, "First round", point)

gain2, point = trier(goal2, point, gain)
point = printOne(name, gain2, goal2, "Second round", point)
```

This results into this:

```
First round

Henry    6 points 18 buts    6 total points
Owen     4 points 12 buts    4 total points
Drogba   2 points 6 buts     2 total points
=======================================================
Second round

Henry    4 points 6 buts     10 total points
Owen     6 points 8 buts     10 total points
Drogba   2 points 5 buts     4 total points
=======================================================
```

Is this what you are looking for?

**EDIT Answer for question in comment**
"Thank you for your help. I have edit my first post in putting the final result. How you add points of the first round with the second ? For the final ranking? "

At the beginning point = `[0,0,0]`
Then the trier method is called for goal1
`trier([18,12,6], [0,0,0], [2,4,6])`
the gain_per_person for goal1 = `[6,4,2]`
at the line `pts = np.add(pts, gain_per_person)`  the `[0,0,0]` of pts and the `[6,4,2]` are added to eachother which results in pts being `[6,4,2]`
this is then returned as the 2nd return value and saved in `point`.

Then the trier method is called for goal2
`trier([6,8,5], [6,4,2], [2,4,6])`
the gain_per_person for the goal1 = `[4,6,2]`
at the line `pts = np.add(pts, gain_per_person)`  the `[4,6,2]` of pts and the `[6,4,2]` are added to eachother which results in pts being `[10,10,4]`
this is then returned as the 2nd return value and saved in `point`.

**EDIT 2**
if the names are `["Henry", "Owen", "Drogba"]`
and the results for goal1 are `[6,4,2]`
and the results for goal2 are `[2,6,4]`
then the desired result is `[8,10,6]`

To put this story in python code

```
points_goal1 = [6, 4, 2]
points_goal2 = [2, 6, 4]
points_total = [0, 0, 0]

for index in range(3):
    print(index)
    print("points_goal1[", index, "] =", points_goal1[index])
    print("points_goal2[", index, "] =", points_goal2[index])
    print()
    points_total[index] = points_goal1[index] + points_goal2[index]

print("=======================================================")
print("points_goal1 =", points_goal1)
print("points_goal2 =", points_goal2)
print("points_total =", points_total)
```

Which gives as a result

```
0
points_goal1[ 0 ] = 6
points_goal2[ 0 ] = 2

1
points_goal1[ 1 ] = 4
points_goal2[ 1 ] = 6

2
points_goal1[ 2 ] = 2
points_goal2[ 2 ] = 4

=======================================================
points_goal1 = [6, 4, 2]
points_goal2 = [2, 6, 4]
points_total = [8, 10, 6]
```

Comment: How you do this http://hpics.li/f84c107 ??? Your result is almost correct

Comment: What do you mean by "How do you do this"? I literally gave you the code. Do I need to explain the code more?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have edit my first post in putting the final result. How you add points of the first round with the second ? For the final ranking?

Comment: In my school, I did not learn imports is it I can get the same result with only functions  par examples ? 
1000 thank you

Comment: `[pts[index] + gain_per_person[index] for index in range(pts.__len__())]` instead of the `np.add` line. You are relatively new to python and programming in general?

Comment: @– Gert Kommer: Yes, i am a newbie  :)  
I would like to use  my code sorry because I dont't understand fully your code. Do have you understand my initial ask ? In fact I want to create a final ranking according the number of points. I must to add the point of the player during the first round and second. 
example:
Henry will 8 points

Comment: Yeah in your question you use 2 different lists for goal2 `[8,6,5]` and `[4,5,6]`. if you use `[4,5,6]` henry has 8 points after goal2.

Comment: First roud  
Drogba 2 points 6 buts, Owen  4 points 8 buts, Henry  6 points  10 buts
Second round 
Henry 2 points 4 buts, Drogba 4 points 5 buts, Owen 6 points 6 buts
Final ranking
Drogba 6 points 11 buts, Henry 8 points 14 buts, Owen 10 points 14 buts
my problem is that I don't know how add points for the first round with the second to get the final result.  :-(

Comment: Do you understand the part below **EDIT 2**?

Comment: For the number the goals it’s OK thank you.
I just modified my first post. Now how add the number of point of first round and second ? 
The name of my function is test() do have you an idea ??? 
https://repl.it/JqTk/0

Comment: add goal1 and goal2 to the parameters of test

Comment: Hello  Gert Kommer, Great !! Thank you a lot... Thank you 1000 times!